# Take Screenshot of container in browser page

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, snapshot

When user clicks on "**Save**" button, I am taking a screenshot of browser page and saving that screenshot in server with help of [this link](http://www.kubilayerdogan.net/html2canvas-take-screenshot-of-web-page-and-save-it-to-server-javascript-and-php/).... it's working fine.

**Requirement** :

Here I want to save only the Content present inside div. So I am displaying some paragraph in Div & taking a screenshot of that div only...

**Issue** :

But along with content, its displaying **white space** in the screenshot.

Below is **Screenshot** saved in server :

[image]

**Html** :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://139.59.24.243/ecom1/site/test/screen/screenshot/js/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://139.59.24.243/ecom1/site/test/screen/screenshot/js/jquery.plugin.html2canvas.js"></script>

<div id="target"> 
<p class="paragraph">some text
</p>
</div>  

<input class="save" type="submit" value="save" onclick="capture();" />
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="save.php" id="myForm">
   <input type="hidden" name="img_val" id="img_val" value="" />
</form>

<style>

.save {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.paragraph {    
    font-size: 25px;
}   

</style>

<script>      

function capture() {
    $('#target').html2canvas({
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            //Set hidden field's value to image data (base-64 string)
            $('#img_val').val(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));           
            //Submit the form manually
            document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
        }
    });
}

</script>
```

**Save.php**

```
<?php

//Show the image
echo '<img src="'.$_POST['img_val'].'" />';

//Get the base-64 string from data
$filteredData=substr($_POST['img_val'], strpos($_POST['img_val'], ",")+1);

//Decode the string
$unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);

//Save the image
file_put_contents('/images/image.png', $unencodedData);
?>
```

**Edit**

When i include the div in **table**, then that extra whitespace will not display , but is there any other way so that without using table, can i remove that whitespace ?

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <div id="target">
            <p>some text</p>
         </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you ask this question every day and then delete it?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for your comment, this is completely different question then previous one, i did't deleted any question , that question is related to `save the user uploaded images` but this is related to `take the screenshot of container`.....

Comment: the jsfiddle and code pen have issues, on jsfiddle your capture function isn't being found, your codepen doesn't load the html2canvas plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set the size for the target element here. before capturing the image.

you could detect which page you are on, then set the sizes from a predetermined list of possible sizes.

this is due to the capture is converting the #target element to canvas.

[image: Capture Code]

but if you have multiple settings/ pages then add a switch with some page casing.

```
function capture() {
    $('#target').html2canvas({
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            //Set hidden field's value to image data (base-64 string)
            $('#img_val').val(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));            

            //Example with pages
            let page = 1; //Page 1? (detect which page you are on then set the value here
            switch(page){
                case 1:
                    // Set Width and Height here.
                    $('#target').css('width', '200px');
                    $('#target').css('height', '200px');
                break;
                case 2:
                    // Set Width and Height here.
                    $('#target').css('width', '450px');
                    $('#target').css('height', '900px');
                break;
                case 3:
                    // Set Width and Height here.
                    $('#target').css('width', '250px');
                    $('#target').css('height', '480px');
                break;
                /* etc etc*/
            }
            //Submit the form manually
            document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , i set the size through as you suggested, but still its displaying empty space when i capture the image.... also instead of using switch(page), if possible please give me dynamic solution, so that it will fit for all heights and widths....

Comment: you need to set the width and height of #target, i cannot help you as i don't know what your future/dynamic solution looks like. i'm in the dark here.

Comment: close the question

Comment: please join https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196735/room-for-dean-van-greunen-and-vickey-colors